# How to gain control of what is returned after a route matches?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

With ASP.NET MVC, when a route matches, the framework will determine the Controller type and then use the `ControllerActivator` class to create a new instance of it and then execute the Action method and  finally return it's result to the request caller.

Just out of curiosity, what if I wanted to intervene exactly between the route and the Controller. Let's say controllers don't fit my needs. Let's say I just need to execute a random method in a class and return it's result.

What would I do then? What would I have to override? Can you please provide the path? A sample code would be appreciated too.

Comment: What is it about a controller action that 'does not fit your needs' -- it just seems that you should be able to 'execute a random method in a class and return it's result' from inside of a controller action.  You are not required to return a view if that is part of what makes you want to avoid controller actions.

Comment: Yes I know @DavidTansey. This is really just out of science :)

Comment: Maybe this will sound stupid, or the "easy" way out - don't use a controller, it's ASP.Net - e.g. "old school" generic handler (no frills ashx). Or go Web API (you just want to "execute a method and return some result").

Answer (score 0):

1. Create your own controller factory which implements IController factory. Something like below.

   public class MyControllerFactory : IControllerFactory
2. Implement IControllerFactory interface
3. Register your new controller factory in Global.asax Application_Start event.

   ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(typeof(MyControllerFactory));

You can check code of DefaultControllerFactory as reference for implementing your own factory.